# C++ unique_ptr problems on delete

Tags: c++, dictionary, unique-ptr

Trying to work and understand c++ unique_ptr...i create some classes for managing resources and work with unique_ptr....all works fine apparently but exiting program Visual Studio crashes with assertion error (is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use) and i dont understand why....someone can help me?

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>

// Include DevIL library to load image files.
//
#include "..\..\Libraries\DevIL\include\IL\il.h"

typedef unsigned char uchar;


class Resource
{
public:
    std::string mFileName;
    std::unique_ptr<uchar[]> mRawData;

    Resource(std::string fileName) : mFileName(fileName) {}

    virtual void Load() = 0;
};

class ResourceBitmap : public Resource
{
private:
    int mSizeX, mSizeY, mBpp;

public:
    ResourceBitmap(std::string fileName) : Resource(fileName) {}

    void Load() override
    {
        ilInit();
        ILubyte imageId = ilGenImage();
        ilBindImage(imageId);

        if (!ilLoadImage(mFileName.c_str()))
        {
            // Error loading image
        }

        mSizeX  = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
        mSizeY  = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        mBpp    = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BYTES_PER_PIXEL);

        mRawData = std::move(std::unique_ptr<uchar[]>(ilGetData()));    // unique_ptr constructor with the raw pointer returned by DevIL
    }
};

class ResourceSound : public Resource
{
public:
    void Load() override
    {

    }
};

class ResourceManager
{
public:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> mResources;

    void AddResource(std::unique_ptr<Resource> resource)
    {
        auto it = mResources.find(resource->mFileName);
        if (it == mResources.end())
        {
            resource->Load();
            mResources[resource->mFileName] = std::move(resource);
        }
    }
};



#define CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <Windows.h>

#include "Resource.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "DevIL.lib")

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    {
        std::unique_ptr<ResourceManager> resourceManager = std::make_unique<ResourceManager>();

        resourceManager->AddResource(std::move(std::make_unique<ResourceBitmap>("d:\\mojito.jpg")));
        //resourceManager->AddResource(std::move(std::make_unique<ResourceBitmap>("d:\\petalo.jpg")));
        //resourceManager->AddResource(std::move(std::make_unique<ResourceBitmap>("d:\\sol.jpg")));
    }

    system("pause");
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not your main problem, but `std::move` should not be used with `std::make_unique`  ; the latter returns by value so the expression is a prvalue already

Comment: `mRawData = std::move(std::unique_ptr<uchar[]>(ilGetData()));` looks like a serious problem. The `ilGetData` returns a pointer into the image's data which you should not be deleting . `unique_ptr` is for resources that you own and you are responsible for cleaning up.

Comment: You probably want to make a copy of the data pointed to by `ilGetData()` at this point (unless the image library guarantees that data's lifetime in which case you can use a raw pointer without copying)

Comment: I'm halfway sure you can still remove a bunch of that code, or? Also, I'm not sure if this is your example code only, but `#defining` macros that control behaviour of system headers after including any other headers (that might in turn include the system headers) may not work as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone...yes..the problem was in mRawData...using raw pointer instead unique_ptr solve all problems...thanks M.M for your help....thanks Ulrich so...sorry for messy code...it should be two separated files but i don't know how to publish it here in two different files and i put it all together..the #define CRTDBGMAP_ALLOC is the first line of another source file..if that was what you was referring...